# Too many composite(multi column )indexing is ok?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, compound-index

Consider we have A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H columns in my table and if  I make composite indexing on column ABCDE because  these column are coming in where clause and then   I want  composite indexing on ABCEF  then I create new composite indexing  on ABCEF  in same table but in a different  query, we want indexing on column ABCGH for that i make another composite indexing in same table,

So my question is can we make too many composite indexes as per our requirements because sometimes our column in where clause gets change and we have to increase its performance so tell me is there any other way to optimise  the query or we can  make multiple composite indexes as per the requirements.

I tried multiple composite indexing and it did not give me any problem till now but still i want to know from all of you that will it give me any problem  in future or is it ok to use only composite indexes and not single index.

Your answers will help me alot waiting for your replies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reat https://use-the-index-luke.com/ by Marcus Winand. It will teach you about designing indexes to help satisfy single queries and multiple different queries.

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB supports up to 64 indexes per table (cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html).

If you try to create a composite index for every permutation of N columns, you would need N-factorial indexes. So for 8 columns, you would need 40,320 indexes. Clearly this is more than InnoDB supports.

You probably don't need that many indexes. In practice, I've rarely seen more than 6 indexes in a given table. All queries that are needed are optimized by one of those.

I understand you said sometimes you change the terms in your query's WHERE clause, so it might need a composite index with different columns.

You can rely on indexes that have a subset of all the columns that would be optimal. That won't be 100% optimized, but it will be better than no index.

You can't predict the optimal set of indexes for a given query until you write that query.

Answer (score 2):

- There is a limit of 64 secondary indexes (at least in InnoDB).
- Order the indexes so that columns being tested with `=` come first.  (The order of those columns in the `INDEX` does not matter.)
- The leftmost columns in an index are the most important.
- There is little or now use in including more than one column that will be searched by a range.
- Study your likely queries, and find the most common combinations of 2 or 3 columns; build indexes starting with those.
- In your two examples (ABCDEFGH and ABCEF), ABC would work for both (assuming at least A and B are tested with `=`).  If you do throw on more columns, that one `INDEX` can still be used for both cases.
- Maybe you would what to declare both ABCDEFGH and BCEFA; This handles your ABCDEF case, plus cases that have B, but not A.  (Remember 'leftmost'.)
- Use the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to find the slowest queries and make better indexes for them.
- More on indexing: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many as you want.  However, each additional index has a cost when updating, inserting or deleting.  The trick is to

1. find common segments and make indexes for those.
2. Or create them as required when queries are too slow.

As an example, if you are "needing" indexes for **ABCDE**, **ABDEF**, and **ABGIH** then create an index on just **AB**

Answer (score 0):

Each index requires space on the disk to be stored, and time to be updated every time you update(/insert/delete) an indexed column value.

So as long as you don't run out of storage or write operations are too slow, because you have to update too many indexes, you are not limited to create as many specific indexes as you want.

This depends on your use case and should be measured with production like data.

A common solution would be to create one index specific for your most important query e.g. in your case **ABCDE**.
Other queries can still use the as many columns from left to right until there is a first difference. e.g. a query searching for **ABCEF** could still use  **ABC** on the previous mentioned index.
To also utilise column **E** you could add a where condition to **D** to your query in a way you know it matches all values e.g. D < 100 if you know there are only values 1-99.